# Is there a player that merge the end of a music with the beginning of the next?

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3-player

In Winamp 3 for Windows, there's a feature that the last 3 seconds of the music is merged with the first 3 seconds of the next music, so there's no "empty space" between the musics.

Is there a way to do this with Rhythmbox? Or is there any player for Ubuntu that has this feature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The feature is called crossfading.

### Rhythmbox

To enable it in Rhythmbox:

1. Click edit in the menu.
2. Click settings.
3. Select the tab Playback.
4. Check Use crossfading backend
5. Select the desired amount of crossfading.
6. Restart Rhythmbox.

### Banshee

It seems that Banshee does not support crossfading. If you wish it you can select that it affects you at https://bugs.launchpad.net/banshee/+bug/135926 and you can also vote for it at http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/21564/.

Answer (score 3):

### [Guayadeque](http://packages.ubuntu.com/guayadeque) [image: Install guayadeque]

This music player comes with a highly configurable crossfader (*Library -> Preferences*):

[image]